# What can be done by "DOT"? (Black Tab Feature)

Tags: metadata

I know that Salesforce has a black tab feature where they could "DOT" an Org (Copy data and metadata) to another org.

What are your experiences on this? Like what were they able to do with this feature? Can they DOT a Production Organization to a Developer Edition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short: no, not really. There are various restrictions on the DOT process, including but not limited to: total organization/data size, switching between editions (generally you can go up, but never down), and moving between pods/instances.

I'd agree you should file a case and check with support, but DOTs are not a magic wand for recreating an org.

Answer (score 1):

Can't speak for how/when SFDC will/won't do it, but a dot copy is a full working copy. Similar to what you get when you request a full sandbox refresh or a trialforce provision. It is complete and can (technically) be done to any org. Don't know if you can morph a prod org into a DE org.

Your best bet is to just file a case; dot copy requests are handled by the support team.